Fabric: Permissions Required for External Application to Write to OneLake
I have a Microsoft Fabric workspace containing a lakehouse. I have a requirement to export data from an external finance system and push the resultant CSV files directly into the 'Files' area of the lakehouse. This is being done using a Service Principal, since Fabric does not support SAS URI or Account key authorization.
I have created the Service Principal, given it a secret, added it to a security group, and granted the SP Contributor access on the workspace containing the lakehouse.
I have also enabled the necessary permissions in Fabric (Service principals can use Fabric APIs, Users can access data stored in OneLake with apps external to Fabric).
For the API permissions in Azure, the Service Principal has Tenant.ReadWrite.All and I have granted admin consent.
I am testing the upload of a file via PowerShell but it is returning an HTTP 403 error (Forbidden)
User is not authorized to perform current operation for workspace '{workspace GUID}' and artifact '{lakehouse GUID}'

StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.NewAzDataLakeGen2ItemCommand

The fact that it is returning a Storage exception suggests I'm missing some permissions and I wonder if my Service Principal needs additional permissions? What delegated permissions do I need? If this was an ADLS Gen2 account, I'd simply add the Service Principal into the Storage Blob Data Contributor RBAC role on the account, but you don't have that option with Fabric.
Update: I tried the file upload via AzCopy and looking at the detailed logs it gave me an "Incorrect Endpoint" error:


Shouldn't need any delegated permissions.  First test your code using your own identity, then create a new service principal who just has Workspace contributor.  Note you can always add a OneLake shortcut to an ADLSGen2 account if you need functionality or auth styles that aren't directly supported in OneLake.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft file upload works fine when using my own identity. When you say create a new Service Principal, presumably it still needs an Application Id and secret? Can you point me to an article that lays out the step-by-step instructions?

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I should also mention that this is an F8 capacity - are there any feature limitations at this level?

That looks like the BLOB API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id, not the ADLS Gen2 API which is the only one OneLake supports.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update?view=rest-storageservices-datalakestoragegen2-2019-12-12  What is AzCopy command you are using, both working and non-working?

I've been doing some further testing and got it working via PowerShell by simply adding the Service Principal as Contributor to the workspace directly (it was previously via a security group). Quite why that should make a difference I don't know, but in any case, it seems like I have solved the problem.

Might just be timing-related.
